Automatic adjustment of arrow endpoints placement of arrows connecting borders of tables
Consider the code below, which produces the tables shown at the bottom of this message. Is it possible to automatically adjust the starting and ending coordinates of the arrows, so that the arrow starts and ends at a table border (likewise the first arrow in figure below)? Thanks!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, tikzmark, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth} % Adjusted minipage width
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 1} \\
\hline
Node & Value \\
\hline
\(\mathbf{A_1}\) & 100 \tikzmark{A1} \\
\hline
\(\mathbf{A_2}\) & 200 \tikzmark{A2} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm} % Adjust the separation width here
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth} % Adjusted minipage width
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Table 2} \\
\hline
\tikzmark{B1} Node* & Value \\
\hline
\(\mathbf{B_1}\) & 300 \\
\hline
\tikzmark{B2}\(\mathbf{B_2}\) & 400 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[->, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm]}, line width=0.3mm] ($(pic cs:A1) + (0.95em,0.5ex)$) -- ($(pic cs:B1) + (-0.65em,0.5ex)$);
  \draw[->, thick, -{Latex[length=2mm]}, line width=0.3mm] (pic cs:A2) -- (pic cs:B2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix and TikZ to draw the arrows by using the Tikz nodes created by nicematrix under the cells, columns and rows of the tabulars.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}[name=A,hvlines]{cc}
\Block{1-2}{Table 1} \\
Node & Value \\
$\mathbf{A_1}$ & 100 \\
$\mathbf{A_2}$ & 200 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\hspace{15mm}
\begin{NiceTabular}[name=B,hvlines]{cc}
\Block{1-2}{Table 2} \\
Node* & Value \\
$\mathbf{B_1}$ & 300 \\
$\mathbf{B_2}$ & 400 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw [->] (A-3.5-|A-3) -- (B-2.5-|B-1) ; 
\draw [->] (A-4.5-|A-3) -- (B-4.5-|B-1) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Perfect solution, @F.Pantigny! Thank you very much indeed!
